# Check first N lines of bash file for string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I am trying to write a bash script that can go through and check only the first N lines of a file to match a specific string. I am able to write a simple command that will check the entire file, but information that is contained in lines greater than N may not be accurate.

Here is my current implementation

```
find . -exec egrep -H -m 1 -l "\<$month/$day/$year\>" {} \;
```

I was thinking of using the head function to trim the files first but this does not seem to be working. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will show you files matching the pattern in the first `N` lines

```
find . -type f | xargs egrep -H -m 1 -n "\<$month/$day/$year\>" | awk -F : '$2 <= N { print $1; }'
```

`egrep` searches for the first occurrence in a file and adds a line number. `awk` then searches for all lines with a line number less or equal to `N` (insert number here) and prints the filename.

Comment: This is working for me except I do not want it to print the line that matches. Any quick fix for that. I am messing around with it right now, but am not really having any luck. I just want the file name

Comment: I could just use `cut` but I would rather not if possible. Just personal preference, I think cut is kinda sloppy sometimes

Comment: @MZimmerman6 Sorry, my fault, bad copying. `awk` already takes care of that. Please see fixed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps like this

```
find -type f | xargs head -N | egrep -H -m 1 -l "\<$month/$day/$year\>"
```

where `N` is number of lines.

Comment: Add " -$N" after head, where N is the number of lines, and you have a good answer

Comment: This won't work, because `egrep` reads from stdin as one big input and stops printing `(standard input)`, if a match is found.

Comment: Yeah Olaf is right, that is not working for me. It is stopping and printing `(standard input)`. Also I am getting `head: Error reading (Path)` where Path is my specified path